# Multiple Aps Failing at Start Up after upgrading to Ventura

Tags: macos, ventura

After upgrading to Ventura 13.0.1 several apps, including Bartender, ChronoSync, and Logitech Options prompt for system permissions, accessibility, full disk, screen recording etc every time I start up. It is the same apps requesting the same permissions every time. When I subsequently go into the new system settings  and look at full disk access or, screen recording both are empty. It's as if Ventura doesn't save the updates to system settings.

This is a real pain because its as if I have to reinstall these apps every time I restart the system, Has anyone else experienced anything like this? I'm running Ventura 13.0.1 on a M1 MBP. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Message I receive from Bartender Startup.

[image]

Comment: Please specify the apps and exactly what happens and when. It might be the best if you focus on one of the apps.

Comment: Did you try deleting Bartender and reinstalling it?

Comment: I did yes, after the reinstall and I give it permissions it works until the next restart.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded to Mac OS 13.1 and the problem has been resolved.  To the moderator **Nimesh Neema** who deleted my original answer to my question. Please explain how my answer above does not answer the question. I find you deleting my answer especially ironic since I both posted the initial question and responded with my experience after upgrading to 13.1

Comment: Let us hope you get feedback ftom Nimesh Neema about that action.